# jQuery methods on original javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Did jQuery add any sort of new functionality to internal JS object like the "anchor" object?

I know you can select via `$("a")`, but what happens if i already have an object selected?

Comment: The answer to your first question is: *no* .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: I missed the first half with this answer.*

*For the first question:* No, jQuery doesn't do this, it adds functionality to jQuery objects which is different.  [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) takes this route, extending DOM elements/properties (though last I heard, they're reversing this in Prototype 2.0).

---

*For the second:* If you have a jQuery object pointing to the anchor just call any method on it, like this:

```
myObject.css('color', 'red');
```

If it's a DOM element you have, just wrap it using [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

```
$(myObject).css('color', 'red');
```